# Refresh secret in azure keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I am using Azure KeyVault REST API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/setsecret) to create secret value in KeyVault. And i can write to keyvault successfully.

But when i am trying to get the same secret value using Azure KeyVault REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret), i couldn't get the value for the secret. Instead i am getting the below error.

**{"error":{"code":"SecretNotFound","message":"Secret not found: SampleTest2"}}**

And my thought on this error is, KeyVault need to be refreshed after importing any secrets. Since it is not refreshed, i thought that i am getting this error.

If my thought is correct, can anyone assist me how to refresh the azure keyvault?

I know the we can manually refresh the keyvault freom azure portal. But i nned to do it via code after updating/importing any secret in the keyvault.

Thanks

Divyasree

Comment: There is no need to refresh anything when you push a secret to KV, it will be immediately available to any further calls. The refresh on the portal simply goes and refreshes the portal data. However you don't supply enough information to accurately understand what your problem might be. Can you share some of the code you're using? When you write the secret, is it available in portal? if so, then there is likely something wrong with your read code.

Comment: To get Secret Values:

Comment: "bearertoken" is the token generated to authenticate the user.

"keyvaultUrl" is the  {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/SampleTest2?api-version=2016-10-01

To get Secret Values:
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(keyvaultUrl);
   httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+bearerToken);
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

Comment: HashMap<String,String> map1 =new HashMap<String,String>();
  map1.put("tag1","sampletag");
  RequestBodyDTO requestBodyDTO = new RequestBodyDTO();
requestBodyDTO.setValue("sampleValue1");
requestBodyDTO.setTags(map1);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
  HttpResponse response = null;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String map = gson.toJson(requestBodyDTO,RequestBodyDTO.class);

Comment: Why don't you use Key Vault SDK?